# Jenkins: deploy to AWS ECS with docker compose

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, docker-compose, amazon-ecs

I have some misunderstanding. I have Jenkins instance, ESC cluster and docker-compose config file to compose my images and link up containers.

After git push my Jenkins instance grabs all sources from all repos (webapp, api, lb) and makes a batch of operations like build, copy files and etc.

After that I have all folders with Dockerfiles in state "ready for compose".

And in this stage I cant get how I should ping my ESC cluster on AWS to grab all images from Jenkins and compose them with my docker-compose.yml config.

I would be glad of any useful information.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

First, you need to push your images from the Jenkins server into [ECR](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/ECR_AWSCLI.html). Push every image individually to an independent repo.

Next, you have to create an ECS cluster. In this cluster, you create an ECS service that runs in the cluster. For this Service, you create and configure a Task Definition to run your linked containers. You don't need to use docker-compose for this: in ECS you define the links between containers in the configuration of the [Task Definition](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/create-task-definition.html). You can add several container definitions to the same Task Definition, and ECS will link them together.

You can automate all of this from your Jenkins server by attaching an Instance Profile to it that allows it to call the ECS API. In order to deploy new images, all you need to do is pushing them to their ECR repos, and create a new Task Definition pointing to them, and update the service that runs these task definitions. ECS will automatically trigger a blue-green deployment on your behalf.

Comment: Ty for the answer. As far as I know esc-cli compose command can convert compose file into the task definitions. I mean I want to use general approach with compose manifest and without creating ecs task definitions in json format manually. What do u think?

Comment: Aha OK, that changes things a bit. I haven't used the ```ecs-cli``` api, but I can see from the [docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/cmd-ecs-cli-compose-service.html) that it creates everything you need by running ```ecs-cli compose --project-name hello-world --file hello-world.yml service scale 2```. It's not clear whether the command pushes the images to ECR, but I can see there's a ```ecs-cli push``` command. Two things to check then: 1) do you see any images listed in ECR? 2) What does the URI for the image in the task definition json file look like?